# Go: How does go run file.go work

Tags: go

The commands `go build` and `go install` compile the files into binaries. Does `go run` compile or interpret the file? I couldn't find explanations online and may have missed it. Appreciate pointers. Thanks!

Comment: Running any of those with the `-x` option will show you all the commands executed.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It's more or less the equivalent of running `go build X.go -o /tmp/random-tmp-folder/exe && /tmp/random-tmp-folder/exe`

Comment: Somehow I am getting two processes being run after I type in `go run temp.go` One says the command used to run it was `go run temp.go` and the other looks more like what you said

Comment: This is the program func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", hello)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}

Comment: @Curious that's the point, `go run` will do that and finish running when the actual process exits.

Comment: Where is the default location of the these temp files created by golang?

Comment: It defaults to the system's tmp directory, on *nix it's usually `/tmp`.

Answer (score 16):

The `go run` command compiles and runs a main package comprised of the .go files specified on the command line. The command is compiled to a temporary folder.

The `go build` and `go install` examine the files in the directory to determine which .go files are included in the main package.

Answer (score 15):

Command `go run` performs project's building under the hood (so yes it builds project)

and with flag --work (`go run --work main.go`) you can see the location of temporary build files.

Also in official documentation (`go1.11`) you can find:

`go run` - compiles and runs the named main Go package.

`go build` - compiles the packages named by the import paths,
along with their dependencies, but it does not install the results.

`go install` - compiles and installs the packages named by the import paths.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike in java, where the bytcode is created and interpreted at the execution time, go creates an executable file that is dependent on the machine being used,like in c, c++.

Comment: In Java, byte code is not generated at the execution time. It is generated during compilation (javac command), on the machine where the code is compiled. The byte code is platform independent. Specific JVM implementations, which are platform dependent, will take care of running the code.