# Should I run server with go run . or ./main and what is the difference?

Tags: go

I have a go server which I normally run like this:

`go build . && ./main`

But online I see many examples using go run . which is better to use and what is the difference?

Comment: What is unclear in the documentation you get from `go help run`, `go help build` and `go help install`?

Comment: You can read the explanation of your question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/28881706/8398189

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From official documentation (`go1.11`):

`go run` - compiles and runs the named main Go package.

`go build` - compiles the packages named by the import paths,
along with their dependencies, but it does not install the results.

`go install` - compiles and installs the packages named by the import paths.

**It means:**

Usually for LOCAL environment it's ok to use `go run`,

but for PROD environment it's better to build your app with `go build` and run `./main`,

but in case you need Go toolchain you must use `go install` because it installs packages and dependencies  and run `./bin/main` (it may make sense in dev/stage environment).

Comment: so go install and then ./main ?

Comment: @CommonSenseCode, `go install` isn't likely to create `./main`. Pay close attention to what each command does. Now with modules and GOCACHE, there's very little difference between `build` and `install` aside from the final build artifact.

Comment: `go install` isn't about dependencies, it builds and puts the binary at `$GOPATH/bin`. `go install && go build` is unnecessary - it just produces two binaries at two different paths. And using `go run` in a dev environment is a very strange choice - I would only ever use `go run` locally, and generally not even then.

Comment: If you want a step to install dependencies, that would be `go get`.

Comment: @JimB `go install` isn't likely to create `./main`, `go install` creates `./bin/main` in $GOPATH.

Comment: For prod it's probably best to `go build` elsewhere and just upload the binary somewhere and run it. There's no reason you should need to install the Go toolchain or run `go install` in production.

Comment: @Adrian I'd written `go install && go build` just to have `main` ring on the place to run `./main`, but yes, you're right it's redundant, so I've updated my answer. Regarding DEV env - my mistake I meant exactly local environment. Thank you!