# Static files don't update while serving them from Go

Tags: linux, ubuntu, go, vagrant, ubuntu-16.04

I started to learn Go, and have a problem with static files handle.
have this:

```
func main() {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))
    http.Handle("/", fs)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

folder structure:

```
main.go

public
    - index.html
```

When I run `go run main.go` and after it, change something in `index.html`, and again run `go run main.go`, view in browser doesn't changed. So I googled a bit and thought that they are in binary file that go compiles, and because of `main.go` wasn't changed, go doesn't recompile it. So I run `go run -a main.go` to force recompile, but it doesn't help.

I clear history and cache in chrome and even try another browser and `curl`, but still see old static files, while in file system there is only new version. So it is not about browsers. Actually one thing that is working is to rename `public` to `public2`(for example) and in `main.go` make same changes, when I see new version of static files in browser.

It is not Go problem, because this example works OK in other users. So it is something with my system. I run that code on default Ubuntu 16.04 in Vagrant.

vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5432, host: 5432
end
```

request header:

```
2017/11/19 18:25:45 request.RequestURI: /
2017/11/19 18:25:45 request.RemoteAddr: 10.0.2.2:50584
2017/11/19 18:25:45 request.TLS: <nil>
2017/11/19 18:25:45 Request Headers:
2017/11/19 18:25:45 Accept : [text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8]
2017/11/19 18:25:45 Accept-Encoding : [gzip, deflate, br]
2017/11/19 18:25:45 Accept-Language : [en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8]
2017/11/19 18:25:45 Cache-Control : [max-age=0]
2017/11/19 18:25:45 Connection : [keep-alive]
2017/11/19 18:25:45 If-Modified-Since : [Sun, 19 Nov 2017 16:24:53 GMT]
2017/11/19 18:25:45 Upgrade-Insecure-Requests : [1]
2017/11/19 18:25:45 User-Agent : [Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36]
```

response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 2010
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Last-Modified: Sun, 19 Nov 2017 16:24:53 GMT
Date: Sun, 19 Nov 2017 18:25:27 GMT
```

CONCLUSION: I run that on another vm and everything work fine, so there is something about vm, but now I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: You should not need to rerun, nor recompile the go app, unless there is some caching going on in the browser you should see changes made to index.html just after refreshing the page.

Comment: I clear history and cache in chrome and even try another browser, but still see old static files, while in file system there is only new version. So it is not about browsers.

Comment: Try curl to see if the index.html changes. I've just recreated your simple example on my machine and it works with firefox just fine.

Comment: curl shows old version too

Comment: You're doing something somewhere wrong but there is no problem with how Go's http.FileServer works. https://imgur.com/a/HnuD7

Comment: I think youre right, here is something about my system, but don't know what and where to look for...

Comment: Try also something like this https://play.golang.org/p/Z1AZ_EthiY just to see if Go is receiving a request every time, or only the first time.

Comment: Also take a look at this https://jeremyfelt.com/2013/01/08/clear-nginx-cache-in-vagrant/, maybe your issue is similar to that.

Comment: Go is receiving a request every time I refresh page. I got no nginx installed.

Comment: You've given your go code but I think that this an environment configuration issue - perhaps including your vagrant config and setup details would be more helpful in solving the issue. Request/response headers would also help

Comment: make sure the file *inside the VM* is being changed, there may be a sync/cache issue with that. sounds like something is caching it... (definitely not related to golang or your code)

Answer (score 0):

[go run](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_run_Go_program) essentially [builds a binary, copies it to a tmp folder and then executes it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28755999/1114274) (its more than that, but good enough for our purposes).

I tested out your example by copying the main.go you provided then doing the following:

```
go run main.go
# in a new tab
curl localhost:8080
#  ==> "Hello world"
echo "2" >> public/index.html
curl localhost:8080
#  ==> "Hello world\n2"
```